# What goes into making a Proxy Server?

Tags: scala, proxy, server

I'm pretty new into development and I'm going to be building a Proxy server for work. I'm not really sure what goes into a building a Proxy server and anything I can find is just telling me to install something and set one up; but I want to be able to build my own. I'm going to be working in Scala so what exactly goes into making one and what does it do?

Comment: A proxy server is an intermediary, or a middle man. basically clients connect to the proxy, the proxy connects to the "real" resource on the clients' behalf. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server. Before anyone can help you, you need to explain what it is you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Look up the implementation of an existing open source proxy server. There you'll see what goes into it.

Comment: Here is a proxy server I wrote for fun with akka http.  You would have to update it for the latest akka-http version though. https://gist.github.com/rklaehn/3aa3215046df2c0a7795

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two major kinds of proxies:

1. reverse proxies
2. forward proxies

Both kinds of proxies may or may not have the following value-added capabilities (this is a sample and nowhere near exhaustive):

1. caching
2. filtering
3. load balancing
4. fault tolerance

I'm going to assume you want to build an HTTP/HTTPS forward or reverse proxy.

Is it a reverse proxy?

An HTTP load balancer in front one or more application servers is a reverse proxy.  In this case the backend server is either fixed, selected based on headers (Host is a popular one), or selected from a pool when load balancing.   The backend may use the same protocol or may use a custom load balancing protocol.  For your case I'd recommend using the same protocol unless there's a very compelling reason not to.

Is it a forward proxy?

An HTTP proxy between end-users and the Internet is a forward proxy.  In this case the proxy establishes a new connection to the requested domain and sends its own HTTP request possibly directly copying the headers and content of the user.  The proxy may choose to allow or deny requests based on domain names, URLs, IP addresses, or content.

Both kinds of proxies do essentially the same thing: take an inbound request and make it to the destination on the requestors behalf.

The basic procedure for a simple proxy is as follows:

1. accept connection from requestor
2. copy all request metadata (headers, parameters)
3. establish connection to destination
4. send request to destination with that metadata

To make that work for a reverse proxy the destination needs to be a parameter of the proxy process (configuration, code, etc.).

To make that work for a forward proxy the requestor needs to have a protocol for expressing the destination.  There are many protocols for this: HTTP. HTTP CONNECT, and SOCKS being the major ones.  In the simplest case the client connects to the proxy server over HTTP and sends the same request they would normally send directly to the destination server.

A novel (as far as I know) thing to enable would be a reverse proxy that accepts connections from backends.  This would allow a DMZ that can't be easily used to attack the backends in the secure zone.

Kate Madsudaira provides [a good description of what proxies do and their benefits at an architectural level](http://www.aosabook.org/en/distsys.html) in the book **The Architecture of Open Source Applications**.